# Gauss measurement at specific point within a magnetic field?

Tags: magnetic-fields

I am reviewing specifications from a manufacturer that produces a cryogenic electromagnet. Their specification indicates that the stray magnetic field is much higher on the x axis than y or z. At 2m from the core, the x axis shows 350 Gauss, y axis shows 100 Gauss, and z axis shows about 40 Gauss.

My question is if I am trying to determine a device's susceptibility to stray fields, and its location is not at the same elevation as the magnet core, is there a way for me to calculate the expected fields at a given point? For example, if a sensor is .5m away on the z axis, but 1m way on x axis - there should be some type of formula that can determine the stray field value?

Thank you

Comment: The manufacturer may provide plots with contour lines of constant stray fields in principal planes of the magnet. Without that you can do only very rough estimates.

Comment: Thank you, I have those measurements. I do not know how to use those values in order to calculate the field value at a specific point in space with relationship to the magnet. That is what I am seeking help on.

Comment: You can interpolate between the contour lines to get a reasonable estimate.